# Android run correct background operations

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How can I run background operations correctly without creating memory leaks or blocking other threads? I first used `asynctask`, but it uses a thread pool which blocks after 5 tasks in background, and passing weak references don't fix the problem of memory leaks. So I need to transfer data between client and server. I think I should use a class that implements `Runnable`, and in the activity I start the runnable with `ExecutorService` (singleThreadExecutor). Then I call submit. I need to get the "Future" from the `ExecutorService` to be able, to cancel the Thread if the activity call `onStop()`. If someone has a better solution for this, please help me. The requirements are that it should block other threads, and I should be cancel able if the activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask are for my point of view the best way to deal with Threads.
I don't know what kind of operations you want to do, but check the [intent service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService)

Runnable are running on the main thread, so if your activity die, it dies too, or you can wipe the stack handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);.

Play with Thread can be tricky, be aware of what you do :)

In this case, you need to set up a loop that check for interrupted exception :)

Good Luck !

Comment: The documentation of Asynctask says that it should be used for tasks that runs max. 3 seconds in background. For longer operations it should not be used.

Comment: Yes this class is designed to handle short term background process like downloading content, I assumed that it was short when you said tranfering data to a server. Have you tried with Volley lib for http task ?

When you talk about memory leak, you talk about the context ? If so try, intent service or JobIntentService (Android 8.0 and +). But in this case you will not be able to stop it when you want.

Comment: I using my own data protocol, i need to upload/download images and videos. So there where big files too. I need to send commands to server and so on. And its working everything fine with Asynctaskl, but the problem is. That when the internet or server is getting slower. The app is lagging and nothing happens until the Asynctasks, which where started before finishing the work. I thing i should just use runnables.